# How to extract number which is of variable length from a string using Substring?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to extract number from a string column.The length of number in string value is not fixed but it is ended with a special symbol underscore(_).I have tried with Substring but unsuccessful.Please suggest,below sample data for the column

Example String :

```
FilePath
1002001_Inv_QCR.tiff
100101_Inv_MAN.Jpg



SELECT SUBSTRING(Filepath,1,6)  from Tblfileinfo
```

Comment: The number is always at the beginning of the string?

Comment: Do the contents of the filepath follow a fixed pattern?

Comment: Are there multiple filenames/numbers stored in a single entry? If som that would require some sort of looping, recursion, etc. If it's just the one, then a substring expression works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, the following could help:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(Filepath, 1, CHARINDEX('_', Filepath) - 1)
FROM
   Tblfileinfo
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, this over killed my problem.How to extract number if the input is like this Inv_100200_Man.txt.

Comment: oookaaay, soooryyy. It was just funny that I had already answered the followup question that @Simhadri was asking... (even though I had answered it by apparently misreading the original question). I am suitably chastized, and will attempt to hold off angering the gods of SO again. All that said, is the answer bad or am I just being punished for childishness?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Value NVarChar(255)
SET @Value = 'Something_1002001_Inv_QCR.tiff'
SELECT SubString(@Value, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', @Value), CharIndex('_', @Value, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', @Value)) - PatIndex('%[0-9]%', @Value))
```

(note: this would also handle the case where the number is NOT at the start of the name)

Specific to the provided table:

```
SELECT SubString(Filepath, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', Filepath), CharIndex('_', Filepath, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', Filepath)) - PatIndex('%[0-9]%', Filepath))
FROM Tblfileinfo
```